# Eclipse says <terminated>, not sure why

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure, when I run this in eclipse it says . What's happening is, the input Y is a year that's less than 10000, and I have to find the next year after that one that has all different digits. For example, 2010 would print 2013 because 2013 is the next year after 2010 with all different digits.

```
package from1987To2013;

public class from1987To2013 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Y is year input
        int Y = 2011;
        //number of digits in Y
        int length = String.valueOf(Y).length();


        //Turns the Y into an int array arrayY
        String temp = Integer.toString(Y);
        int[] arrayY = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
        {
            arrayY[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
        }

        //first for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            //find every value from Y to 10000
            int a = Y + i;

            //changes if its true or not
            boolean bool = true;

            //this loop goes through once if y = 2, twice if y = 33, thrice if y = 456, four times if y == 4666, etc
            int d = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < length; b++)
                //d is the b - 1 which will be compared with the position at b
                d = b-1;
                int b = 0;
                //checks if they're all equal
                if (arrayY[d] != (arrayY[b])) {
                } else {
                    bool = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (bool = true){
                System.out.print(a);
        }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: `if (bool = true){` should be `if (bool == true){` or even simpler `if (bool){`

Comment: d = b - 1 when b = 0 sets d to -1 and this is used as an index in arraY.

Comment: Did yo try to debug and step through the code?

Comment: This loop `for (int b = 0; b < length; b++)` probably needs braces { } for the indented code. But you also define a new variable `int b = 0;` within that block. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As well as changing the code as per @ZouZou's comment, I'm not quite sure why, but i had to change this line:

```
System.out.print(a);
```

to

```
System.out.println(a);
```

in order to get any output from eclipse.

p.s. your logic doesn't work, but at least this gives you output so you can debug it now.

Comment: I don't believe this is entirely correct. The reason `println()` seems to work while `print()` doesn't is because the "terminated" message is covering the single line outputted by `print()`.  It's there, you just can't see it.